# Discrete monotone decreasing distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am working on a metric (i.e., a positive real number less than 10k) that updates daily and gets stored in a database. Together with this value, I also want to keep a value corresponding to the weighted average of all the values computed so far. Ideally, more recent values have more significance than older values, hence the weight for more recent values is bigger than the weight for older values.

In other words, if $d$ is the day and $v_d$ is the corresponding value, then the weighted average $h_d$ from day $1$ and up to $d$ included is:

$$
\begin{equation}
h_d = \sum_{i=1}^d{w_i v_i}, \;\; w_i < w_j \; \forall \; i < j
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
$$

If $\hat{d}$ is the most recent day, then it also holds that:

$$
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{\hat{d}}{w_i} = 1
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
$$

The problem boils down to finding the values for the $w_i$s. My first idea was to choose a multiplicative factor $m \in (0, 1)$, so that $h_1 = v_1$ and for each $d > 1$:

$$
\begin{equation}
h_d = m \cdot v_d + (1 - m) \cdot h_{d-1}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
$$

Which has the property of making the daily computation extremely easy (no need to compute weights for each of the previous days!), but leaves me with an open problem: how to choose $m$?

One obvious choice would be $m = 0.5$, that has the nice property of being the smallest number to not "undershoot" for smaller values of $\hat{d}$. E.g., if $m = 0.3$ and $\hat{d} = 2$, then

$$
\begin{equation}
h_{\hat{d}} = 0.7 h_1 + 0.3 h_2
\tag{4}
\end{equation}
$$

This makes $h_1$ twice as "important" as $h_2$. Is this a good idea, or is there a better solution?

As a follow up, I had a colleague come up and tell me that it would be better if I used a more statistically sound, distribution-like weighing. Since I'm all for mathematical zeal, I gave a look to [this Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#With_finite_support), but I couldn't find anything that seemed appropriate to my case. Any suggestions on this matter would be much appreciated, too. The best case scenario would be something as easy to compute as (3).

Answer (score 1):

In economics and related disciplines, it is common to use a discount factor to evaluate streams of profits etc (usually to discount future values rather than past values, but the idea is the same). For example if we have discount factor $
\beta\in(0,1)$, then the "present value" $V_T$ at $T$ of the stream of daily values $v_1,\ldots,v_T$ is given by

$$V_T=\beta^{T-1}v_1+\beta^{T-2}v_2+\cdots+\beta v_{T-1}+v_T=\sum_{t=1}^{T}\beta^{T-t} v_T.$$

This means that

$$V_T=v_T+\beta V_{T-1}.$$

The choice of $\beta$  is arbitrary. It depends upon how much you care about past values relative to present values.

---

If you want, you can normalize $V_T$. Suppose the daily values are in $[0,\bar{v}]$. Then

$$0\leq V_T\leq \overline{v}(1+\beta+\beta^2+\cdots+\beta^{T-1})=\frac{\overline{v}(1-\beta^T)}{1-\beta}$$

So if we let $$\overline{V}_T=\frac{1-\beta}{\overline{v}(1-\beta^T)}V_T$$

then $\overline{V}_T\in[0,1]$.

Comment: The $v_i$s change every day, that's the whole point of calculating the average. My approach is entirely motivated by the fact that more recent values are more important than older ones.

Comment: I only assumed the $v_i$ were all the same to get an upper bound on $V_T$ and calculate a normalizing factor. I did not assume that the $v_i$ were all the same in $V_T$ in the formula I gave at the end.

Comment: Mmm... So in the last equation could I just substitute $\bar{v}$ with $max(v_i)$?

Comment: See my edit, which I think is a bit clearer now. $\overline{v}$ *is* the maximum daily value

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia's [moving average page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) has some good information on the subject. Without a clear objective for the moving average value, or more information about the context that drives daily variation, I don't see any reason to prefer one approach over another.

Comment: Thanks for this. So apparently I was calculating the exponential moving average, good to know. Unfortunately it doesn't really give an approach on how to calculate the weighting factor(s), but nonetheless a useful read.